# Does MongoDb automatically filter out harmful js code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Right now, I am building an app that uses mongo db and node js. I am wondering mongo db alone will help filter out any malicous code that could be submitted.

E.g: will mongo db filter out this code:
`<script> //malicous code here  </script>`

I am hoping someone can help me out with this question.

Comment: That's not malicious code - that's just a string. Same if I gave you a note that said "Buy me a pizza"  - it's just some text. Are you trying to *execute* this? Because only then it'd be a problem. Same with my note, if you decide to take it as a command instead of storing it with other pieces of paper with text on them.

Comment: I used it as an example

Comment: Well...and what is the example supposed to be? Strings are not executable code. Unless you plan to execute them blindly, in which case, I don't see how MongoDB can save you from that.

Comment: Are you concerned about [NoSQL-Injection](https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb.html)? If yes, have a look at [mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-sanitize)

Answer (score 0):

You worry about XSS, but storing Javascript is harmless in your database. The point when it could become harmful is when you execute this Javascript. Since your example has a script tag wrapped around the script, it's safe to presume that we speak about the script being embedded into the browser.

But, to prevent that from happening, you will need to escape your user content. You will need to escape your content when generating HTML unless you want to allow code to be embedded into it. Here's a tool that you can use for that purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator.

Then you will be able to

```
let escapedInput = validator.escape(userInput);
```

or even:

```
function escapeInputs(inputs) {
    let outputs = (Array.isArray(inputs) ? [] : {});
    for (let key in inputs) {
        outputs[key] = validator.escape(input);
    }
    return output;
}
```

The above does not deal with nested inputs. That can also be handled, but for the sake of brevity at this point I presumed that you have a key-value pair object of noncomposite values, or an object of noncomposite items.